# How to keep the selected item from select in a react application to be same on reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**How to keep the selected item from select in a react application to be same on reloading the page?**
I have to maintain the state as per the last selection by the user on reloading. please help me edit this code so that it works properly on reloading the page with same state.

```
function handleChangeBranch(value: any) {
        AdvertiseService.fetchNewStore(
          `${value}`,
          (store: any) => {
            // brand = store;
            setSelectedBranch(store);
          },
          () => { },
          () => { }
        );
        setBranchChanged(true)
    
      }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <Button className="city-selection-btn">
                    <Select
                      defaultValue={branches?.branches?.length === "1" ? selectedBranch?.name : "choose location"}
                      style={{ width: 120, border: "none" }}
                      onChange={handleChangeBranch}
                    >
                      {branches &&
                        branches.branches?.map((branch: any) => (
                          <Option
                            value={branch.id}
                            className="advertise-branch-list-item"
                            key={branch.id}
                          >
                            {branch.name}
                          </Option>
                        ))}
                    </Select>
                  </Button>
```

Comment: Have you Googled how to persist React state in local storage? A quick search shows many resources on this exact requirement. Here's the first result: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/persisting-react-state-in-localstorage/

Comment: @Jayce444 can you help me edit the above code such that it works? I am new to react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the selected value on `localStorage` or URL, then in `componentDidMount` you can get the value you stored (on `localStorage` or URL) and set to the state that you bind to the `Select` component value.

P.S. you can try `localStorage` without installing any library:

`localStorage.getItem("branch")` to get data
`localStorage.setItem("branch", value)` to set data

Comment: Can you help me edit the above code such that it works? I am new to programming

Comment: can you change the code?